# onfocusout event defined within onfocus event not calling successfully

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a field when the user clicks outside of a textarea. But, I also want to check that the input is different from the original input before sending the update request to the server. Im trying to use onfocus and onfocusout to accomplish this as follows:

```js
function updateTitle(){
 var title = document.getElementById("info_title");
 var oldTitle = title.value;
 title.onfocusout = function(){
  var newTitle = title.value;
        if(newTitle != oldTitle){
            update();
        }
 }
}
```

```html
<textarea id='info_title' onfocus='updateTitle()'>Title</textarea>
```

The onfocus function is called, but the onfocusout function never gets called successfully. It is not a problem with onfocusout, because if I change "onfocus=" to "onfocusout=" in the html, the function is also called succesfully. Is there a problem with defining an onfocusout function within on onfocus function in this way? Why does the onfocusout part not run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is .onblur not .onfocusout.

```js
function updateTitle(){
    var title = document.getElementById("info_title");
    var oldTitle = title.value;
    title.onblur = function(){
        console.log('focus out');
        var newTitle = title.value;
        if(newTitle != oldTitle){
            update();
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<textarea id='info_title' onfocus='updateTitle()'>Title</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, although I thought the only difference between onfocusout and onblur was bubbling